# Installing "Mobile Development with .NET" in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mobile

I am trying to use Xamarin and for that purpose I am trying to install "Mobile Development with .NET" in visual studio 2019 using the installer.

I am not able to download anything as I can see "0 KB" are remaining to download. How to solve this problem?

I am using windows 10 on my 2 years Lenovo yoga laptop.

I provided screen shot for reference.[Visual Studio 2019 Installer Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kftL.png)

Comment: Normally this means you have it already installed? Have you tried to create a xamarin project?

Comment: Yes. But each time I am being requested to install new component. I want to install them all in one go.

Comment: For example, I am being to install different versions of Android SDK

Comment: You can try to uninstall the VS, and then reinstall it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install xamarin.NET 7.0 SDK (v7.0.102) - Windows x64 Installer!

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.102-windows-x64-installer

Comment: VS2019 does not officially support the .NET 7 SDK, so installing it would be pointless. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/compatibility#-visual-studio-2019-support-for-net-development).